# Threadsafe delete in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, delete-operator

My question is not how to make this feature from scratch, but whether my implementation can be used.

I have the next classes:

```cpp
    class PointerStorage
    {
    private:
        static std::mutex m;
        static std::unordered_set<void*> pointers;
    public:
        static inline void add(void* ptr){
            m.lock();
            PointerStorage::pointers.insert(ptr);
            m.unlock();
        }
        static inline bool tryRemove(void* ptr) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(m);
            return PointerStorage::pointers.erase(ptr);
        }
        static inline bool hasPtr(void* ptr) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(m);
            return PointerStorage::pointers.find(ptr) != PointerStorage::pointers.end();
        }
    };
```

```cpp
    class Deletable
    {
    public:
        void* operator new(size_t size) {
            void* p = malloc(size);
            PointerStorage::add(p);
            return p;
        }
        void operator delete(void* ptr) {
            if (PointerStorage::tryRemove(ptr)) {
                free(ptr);
            }
        }
    };
```

My idea is to inherit from `Deletable` if necessary and use the operators

But I'm wondering if such a situation is possible:

- I create an object in variable `OBJ`, delete it.
- I create a new object in another variable, its address becomes the same as it was in `OBJ` and the delete operation on `OBJ` affects my new object.

Comment: Why do you need this? Any mutating operation on an object shared between threads requires locking. Why single out deletion? Anyway I don't see a problem in the situation you describe. A new object address may be the same as an old deleted object address, how does it affect anything?

Comment: But I have an event system and its possible to have the same pointers in different listeners (or even the same listeners, since they can be executed in different threads).

Comment: I'm not sure why you think it matters. While an object is alive, only that object has this address. When an object is deleted, there are no objects with that address any more, and it can be reused. If you keep addresses of potentially deleted objects around your program, then you have a problem which has nothing to do with threads.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you should not assume that the pointer used for an old object is not reused for a new object.

Sometimes you'll want to make such assumption.

For multi-threaded programs this situation when you want to be sure that pointer is not re-used is ABA problem. Simply put, this problem occurs when you do compare-exchange of an old pointer with a new pointer, but you can't be sure that the old pointer is indeed the old pointer.

One of solutions is basically to keep old pointer around for some time, this is called [Hazard pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_pointer).

Other is to rely not just on pointer value, but also on a counter (although counter can still wrap around, the probability of failure is lower).

Generally, the best solution is not to run into the situation when you need the assumption that old pointer is not reused. *ABA problem* is special case, however, specific to lock-free, when avoidance likely to mean not having lock-free algorithm at all.